MLFlow UI not loading - missing static content
I have deployed an MLFlow server using mlflow server .... When visited its deployed URL https://some.url I would see a blank page and couldn't load. Oddly, this is not an issue locally on local host.
Investigating the browser's console I see a bunch of errors giving 404 for static (.../mlflow/build) files.
What am I doing wrong?

Use https://some.url/ instead of https://some.url I don't know why but it works.
